# Egg donation from a mamzer

Tags: halacha, women, contemporary-halacha, mamzer, even-haezer

According to Halacha, is it permissible for a Jewish woman who is a Mamzer to [donate her eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_donation) to help a non-Mamzer Jewish woman become fertile? Or no, because Mamzerim are prohibited from “entering the congregation of Israel” would it be prohibited? If permissible, would the children be mamzerim or no? One reason why it would matter is because there is a discussion amongst the poskim whether a child from an egg donation can have two halachic mothers (their egg donor and gestational mother).

Comment: This asks about the permissibility of the donation, but note even if permissible the kid might still be a mamzer which (to say it lightly) is probably better to avoid.

Comment: Are there rabbis that allow eggs to be donated?

Comment: @DoubleAA that's part of the question I think - would the child be a mamzer?

Comment: So clearly I'm not up to speed on the 'mamzer' ethical debate, but based on the simple reading... How can she be a Jewish woman and also a mamzer? Would she not be a Gentile? She's not supposed to be in the congregation at all. https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0

Comment: @PaulWalker a mamzer is Jewish, we understand "not allowed in the congregation" to mean that s/he cannot marry a Jew with regular status, only those who are in other ways separate from the marriage pool, such as other mamzerim, freed slaves, etc.

Comment: What does it mean "*to help a non-Mamzer Jewish woman*"? Psychologically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just go with "Not recommended."

Today, most poskim in both Israel and America will shrug on questions of which mother -- egg or host -- is recognized by halacha, and be strict both ways. (Rabbi Aharon Soloveitchik zt"l forcefully opined that it was the host mother, and only the host mother, but -- today the most common reaction you'll hear from rabbis is "let's play it safe.")

Rabbi Willig has a YUTorah mp3 where he notes that according to Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, mamzer status is conferred upon the next generation only when everything occurs naturally. A mamzer could do IVF and the child would be a non-mamzer. By that logic, then, the donor egg from a mamzeret would not cause the next generation to be mamzerim. Rabbi Willig notes that according to this opinion, you'd have a married couple conceiving all their children through IVF for purely religious, not medical, reasons.

However common practice today is not to rely on that opinion of Rabbi Feinstein.

So while there were some notable opinions (past tense) that this would theoretically not pass on mamzerut, today's poskim would not rely on that. So let's not create any more problems.